# Comparing TextBox to Table fields

Tags: vba, textbox, ms-access-2007

This is my code:

```
 Private Sub Command34_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("sus-Table", dbOpenDynaset)
    Dim temp As String
        If Nametxt = rs![Name] And ID = rs![ID] And Address_1 = rs![Address 1] _
        And Address_2 = rs![Address 2] And City = rs![City] And State = rs![State] Then
            MsgBox "True"
        Else
            MsgBox "False"
        End If   
End Sub
```

With this code, it returns true as long as all fields are populated (and they match of course).

However, if a fields ie. Address 2 is empty as not all Address's need a 2nd line it returns "`False`" even if they match.

I am not sure how to compare them even if they are empty.

Any help in this mater would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the old problem of comparing **Empty** with **Nulls**, I suggest re-writing like this:

```
And Address_2 & "" = rs![Address 2] & ""
```